# Pyinstaller и pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

Имеется проект, где фигурирует pyqtgraph. При компиляции в PyCharm график работает как надо. Однако, после компиляции проекта в .exe через pyinstaller, график отказывается строиться. При компиляции ошибок не возникало. В чем может быть проблема?

Команда для pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "Al2O3.txt;." --add-data "C.txt;." --add-data "Fe.txt;." --add-data "Fe3C.txt;." --add-data "NaCl.txt;." --add-data "Si.txt;." --add-data "SiO2.txt;." --add-data "base.txt;." --onedir -w main.py
```